# Spring security with REST and JSF

Tags: rest, jsf-2, spring-security

My requirement is to integrate JSF along with spring-security for web app. I am able to do this. But, I also need to implement REST API from spring security to be consumed by my mobile app.
Is there a way where we can use 2 different security realms in spring security? Can someone please provide any tutorial or working example?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define multiple security realms which are separated by the given url pattern:

```
<!-- Configure realm for rest -->
<security:http pattern="/rest/**" ...>
  ...
  ...
</security:http>


<!-- Configure realm for jsf -->
<security:http pattern="/jsf/**" ...>
  ...
  ...
</security:http>
```

Comment: I did tried your solution, but configuring multiple security realms was not working perfectly fine, there was some fault in my way of implementation. Do you have any working example or sample for configuring multiple security realms?